# How to add standard Django models to fixtures output?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-fixtures, django-flatpages

I try to test extended version of Django flatpages and need to create fixture for it. It's incredibly straightforward to create one for a custom model. For example, to create a fixture for a `auth.User` model, I should execute the following command in terminal:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata auth.User > /path/to/fixture.json
```

How can I do the same thing for the `django.flatpages` module? *(see the explanation below)*

---

I extended the `django.contrib.flatpages.models.FlatPage` model as follows:

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

class FooProject(models.Model):
    pass

class FooFlatPage(FlatPage):
    project = models.ForeignKey(FooProject)
```

The **code above will create 4 tables** in a database when I execute the `migrate` command (1 for `FooProject`, 1 for `FooFlatPage` and [2 for Django Flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/#how-it-works)).

Now when I try to execute `dumpdata` for my module:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata my_module > /path/to/fixture.json
```

...I'll get dump of **only 2 tables** (except flatpages tables). The `fixture.json` file:

```json
[
  {
    "model": "my_module.fooproject",
    "pk": 1
  },
  {
    "model": "my_module.fooflatpage",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "project": 1
    }
  }
]
```

**Question:** How I can create a data dump for all (4) tables?

---

When I try to add `--verbosity=3` argument the same output.